# migrating a project from VS2008 to VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I am migrating a project from VS2008 to VS2013. Currently am facing a issue while running the application.
It says:

```sh
**Debug assertion failed**
Program C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\mfc120d.dll
FILE: f:\dd\vctools\vclibs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\doctempl.cpp
LINE: 25
```

This is the place in code am getting issue:

```
cpFormDefDocTemplate = new CMultiDocTemplate(
        MAIDR_MAINFRAME,
        RUNTIME_CLASS(EHF_ManagerDoc),
        RUNTIME_CLASS(EHF_ManagerChildFrame),       // main SDI frame window
        RUNTIME_CLASS(EHF_ManagerView));
```

Am not sure how to go ahead with this. Required help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which versions of Visual C++ Redistributable Packages are installed ?

Comment: VS2008 and VS2013

Comment: Are you looking at the right call stack level for the assert?  That looks like client code (i.e. your code), or is that MFC code?  Literally open up f:\dd\vctools\vclibs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\doctempl.cpp (or wherever you actually have it installed - it probably is not f:...).  Make sure it's the VS2013 source.  Go to line 25.  My version (VS2008) of that file is in the ctor of the CDocTemplate class with a bunch of ASSERTs.  It's there that the assertion is failing (probably in the call of YOUR code you showed).

Comment: [Assertion Failed Dialog Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/assertion-failed-dialog-box). So go ahead, press *"Retry"* (as the dialog has told you already). That'll tell you, which condition you failed to establish. This is a bug in your code, not MFC. Nor is it related to the migration.

Comment: Yeah, I have checked the code in the mentioned path. It is VS2013 source. The same code it is working in VS2008. Why not in VS2013?

Comment: For more details about Microsoft C++ porting and upgrading,I suggest you could refer to the Doc:[Microsoft C++ porting and upgrading guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/visual-cpp-porting-and-upgrading-guide?view=vs-2019)

Comment: *"The same code it is working in VS2008."* - It probably wasn't working in VS2008 either. It just didn't produce a compile-time error. *"It is VS2013 source."* - Sure, that's the code executing on your behalf, though. It's not that code, that's wrong. It's the arguments you are passing, that fail to comply to the contract. Without a [mcve], however, we cannot do much but guess. That's neither an efficient nor effective approach to solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "I have checked the code", what is the actual ASSERT statement?  It's definitely not the code you have in your posting.  Show THAT code (the code where the ASSERT statement is).

For example, here is the code from VS2008, and I have highlighted around line 25 (VS2013 is probably similar, but not exact):

[image]

This is the code you need to look at.  Your code is your CTOR, which is implicitly chaining back to this MFC ctor, which is causing the ASSERT.  Your Doc, Frame, or View is not ported correctly.  The specific ASSERT will tell you which one (could actually be all 3 and it's just ASSERTing on the first one so far).